# Add padding to childs with each parent

Tags: html, css

wanted to know if it`s possible without javascript to add padding to child items with each "folder" element if there is more than one. 
Which in hardcode would look like this:

```
folder folder inner {
    padding-left: 14px;
}
folder folder folder inner {
    padding-left: 28px;
}
folder folder folder folder inner {
    padding-left: 42px;
}
folder list item {
    padding-left: 14px;
}
folder folder list item {
    padding-left: 28px;
}
folder folder folder list item {
    padding-left: 42px;
}
```

Visuals:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo2Za.jpg

Comment: Your question with visual provided makes little to no sense.
You should check `CSS Selectors`

Comment: What you tried it? What does your *actual* HTML and CSS look like?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to think about the CSS a bit harder. Without knowing your exact element structure, this seems like it would suffice, replacing all of your example code and providing for means to extend it out further.

```
folder > folder { padding-left: 14px } / *all child folders of a folder get 14px */
folder > list > item {padding-left: 14px }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think below is a nifty way of doing it.

```
folder * *{
 padding-left: 14px;
}
```

basically every element within a folder will get a padding of 14px. It will look just like the way you want it to look in your link since the padding will stack with each child's parent.

Comment: Well, I'm about to downvote your answer, because it is wrong.  It won't recreate his CSS rules.  : )

Comment: @JohnGreen green is right. I just added an extra asterisk.

Comment: @JohnGreen I did that on purpose. His post made it seem that he only wanted the folder element after the first one to have 14px. The code was intentional. But I agree, I think your code is more of what the OP wants.